# Measure benzene with an Arduino

Tags: sensor, gas-sensor

So,
I need to measure the concentration of Benzene in air. I have an Arduino Zero to read analog or digital value.

I found out the sensor [MQ-135](https://homotix_it.e-mind.it/upld/repository/File/datasheet%20mq-135.pdf). The problem is that, if I'm right, the sensor reacts also to different gasses as NH3 and alcohol.

Is the sensor reliable for such a measure or do I need to look somewhere else? Adapting sensors to the Arduino analog input is not a problem nor power supply of the sensor. My project measure temperature and humidity so, I can also adapt the measure to these two factors.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with the Arduino platform. I suggest you remove that from the question and just say that you will be monitoring the output with a 0 to 5 V microcontroller ADC.

Comment: Arduino zero is 0 - 3.3 V...

Comment: OK. So only that ADC specification is all that needs to be in the question in relation to the microcontroller - if it is needed at all.

Comment: I don't think there is a specific sensor for only benzene in market, unless some proprietary ones. These cheap sensors respond to a class of organic compounds, rather than a specific organic compound.

Answer (score 0):

If the sensing resistance would be 100kOhm, what would be your verdict? CO2? NH4 in somewhat less concentration?
This sensor measures several gases, so it could be anything!

So, either pick a sensor that solely measures benzene (no idea if it exists) or pick a few more different sensors that e.g only measure alcohol and NH3 and another that only measures NH3 and CO2 etc and make a kind of truth table to determine the real gas based on the values of all these sensors.

(Above sensor examples are illustrative, I don't know by heart what combinations there are)
Quick search on internet shows e.g. CJMCU-4541 would be a candidate to exclude CO / NO2 / H2 / NH3 / CH4 etc.